# EF Core .NET package all layers cqrs error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I created a clean-architecture .NET command and I am just two packages add domain layer I want to scaffold but build not succeed because all layer have error what is that ? What happened?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QGQX.png

Comment: It seems downgrading `entity-framework-core` version from `5.0.10`to `5.0.0`will solve your issue.

Comment: Hey, next time just copy and past the output text, not capture the half of it from screen